# Custom WP_Query breaks default behaviour of viewing right post associated with tax-term!

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, order

I have a custom-taxonomy for a custom-post-type just like categories.

I've used the standard loop in my `taxonomy-event_type.php` template so far …

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

This meant that the template only showed the posts associated with the current term (category) the post was in. So on `url/event_type/workshops` only all posts that were set to "workshops" in the backend would appear.

Now i've changed that standard loop to a custom loop where I'm passing some args so I can sort the posts by a meta-value (the event date)

```
$args = array(
    "post_type" => "wr_event",
    "meta_key" => "_wr_event_date",
    "orderby" => "meta_value_num",
    "order" => "ASC"
    //"terms" => 
    );

    $wr_events = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $wr_events->have_posts() ) : while ( $wr_events->have_posts() ) : $wr_events->the_post();
```

This works perfect. Only thing. It breaks the standard behaviour for the term (category) I'm currently viewing.

So with this custom loop when viewing `url/event_type/workshops` or `url/event_type/lectures` always the same posts appear! How can I again view only the posts associated with the current term "workshops" or "lectures"?

Thank you for your help!

edit:

if I do …

```
$current_cat = get_query_var( 'event_type' );
echo $current_cat;

$args = array( …
```

The `$current_cat` holds the right term (category) I'm currently in. Only problem is that the posts in the loop are always the same. How can I filter by this term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You second query performs an entirely new query and does not have the terms set.

Besides, it's not as efficient to 'redo' the query. Instead, hook into [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and change the order there:

```
function change_order_for_events( $query ) {
    //Check if currenty query is the 'main query' and event type taxonomy being viewed 
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_tax('event_type')) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_wr_event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_order_for_events' );
```

For **bonus points** you might want to check that the 'orderby' and 'order' paramters are not set - that way ordering by date becomes default for events on the event type taxonomy pages but can be overridden if required.

All [conditionals are available](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to you.

Comment: Wow, thank you that looks promising, but doesn't work for me! I've gone back to the standard loop in my `taxonomy_event_type.php` template and inserted your function into my `functions.php` … however the posts in my taxonomy template appear in theier `post_date` order and not in their event-order. Did I miss anything? Of course the default behaviour with just showing the right posts associated with its "category" would be back that way - exactly what I want. Just the sorting doesn't take affect.

Comment: Should have been `$query->is_main_query()` (3.3+ only). You should put WP into debug mode when developing - that should have flagged up the error.

Comment: Great answer. If you only want to show future events you can also add $yesterday = time() - 24*60*60; $query->set('meta_value', $yesterday); $query->set('meta_compare', '>'); (this will show future events and events in the last 24 hours)

Comment: @Offroff - yup, but a better way would be to use the [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) parameter :).

Comment: One more question … can I do the same sorting for the archives page? I added `'has_archive' => 'events'` to my custom-post-template. `/events` displays now my "archive.php" file where I already do this for my headline `elseif ( 'wr_event' == get_post_type() ) : ?>` - my post-template is called "wr_event". I have two probably little questions with this. 1.) How can I also sort the posts on the archive page with the mate-key? Of course just for my events? And how can I only display events that are "over". Right now all events show up in the archive …

Comment: You're probably better off starting another question. But Yes, use `is_post_type_archive('wr_event')` and yes us `meta_query`

Comment: Thank you, I did … http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48652/sort-custom-posts-in-archive-php-via-meta-key Maybe you could help me out here. Thanks again for your awesome help!

Comment: A problem occurs with this function … http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49071/custom-post-type-pre-get-posts-and-has-archive-hiding-posts-in-backend Maybe you have a solution for me … thank you very much!