# Sort custom-posts in archive.php via meta-key?

Tags: archives, pre-get-posts

this question is strongly related to this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48607/custom-wp-query-breaks-default-behaviour-of-viewing-right-post-associated-with-t) where I already got a working answer.

I have a custom-post-template named "wr_event" and a custom-taxonomy named "event_type".

This "event-posts" have a meta-box where I set the event date and I use this …

```
function change_order_for_events( $query ) {
    //only show future events and events in the last 24hours
    $yesterday = time() - 24*60*60; 

    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_tax('event_type') ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_wr_event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', $yesterday );
        $query->set( 'meta_compare', '>' );
    }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_order_for_events' );
```

… to sort all "event-posts" via its event-date.

This works just fine and does exactly what I want.

Only thing that doesn't work so far is the "archive.php" where I want the same to take effect.

I added `'has_archive' => 'events'` to my custom-post-template. `/events` displays now my "archive.php" file where I already use `is_post_type_archive('wr_event')` for my headline.

However I want my archived events also to be in its right date-order. So the same function above `change_order-for_events()` should work on my "archive.php" template. Of course in this case the function should show just old events that have already taken place.

Any idea how I could do that?

**update:**
I'm storing the timestamp with the [MetaBox and CustomFields Class](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress)

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id'         => 'event_date',
    'title'      => 'Event Date',
    'pages'      => array( 'wr_event', ),
    'context'    => 'normal',
    'priority'   => 'high',
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Event Date Picker',
            'desc' => 'The date the event takes place',
            'id'   => $prefix . 'event_date',
            'type' => 'text_date_timestamp',
        )
    ),
);
```

I query it in my template files with

```
$wr_event_fields = get_post_custom();
$wr_event_fields['_wr_event_date'][0];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the [appropriate conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):

```
function change_order_for_events( $query ) {
    //only show future events and events in the last 24hours
    $yesterday = current_time('timestamp') - 24*60*60; 

    if ( $query->is_main_query() && (is_tax('event_type') || is_post_type_archive('wr_event')) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_wr_event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

        //Get events after 24 hours ago
        $query->set( 'meta_value', $yesterday );
        $query->set( 'meta_compare', '>' );

       //Get events before now
       //$query->set( 'meta_value', current_time('timestamp') );
       //$query->set( 'meta_compare', '<' );
    }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_order_for_events' );
```

This will alter the main query for term archives for the taxonomy `event_type` and archives for the post type `wr_event`.

Comment: Thank you, just perfect. Last question I have is how I can only display events which have already taken place - with their event-date in my archive? So the archive should sort them just like it does with your updated code but only show events that are over … any ideas on that too?

Comment: How are you storing the end timestamp? Its simply a matter of altering the `meta_compare` and `meta_value` parameters...

Comment: I updated my question with the sample code. I store the timestamp as unix timestamp with a custom class. This class just extends the standard metabox stuff …

Comment: See updated answer - just use the `meta_compare` and `meta_value` as appropriate (commented out is how to get events before today).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the meta_query parameter in the WP_Query [heres the link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

and try something like this:

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(      
    array(
        'key' => '_wr_event_date',
        'value' => $yesterday,
        'compare' => '>'
    )
)
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Normally I'd use `meta_query` too. But this doesn't work unfortunately: you have to set `meta_key` when ordering by `meta_value`/`meta_value_num` even if a key is set in `meta_query` (presumably because of ambiguity that arises when you have multiple arrays in `meta_query`).